# YOLOv3 - I can import yolo_loss but not yolo_head when both are in the same file

Tags: python, python-import, yolo

I'm currently working on a keras implementation (and Tensorflow 1.13) of YOLOv3 and the pruning (with keras surgeon for now) of this model (based on this repo : https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3).
I basically have this issue : https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/issues/48, but the maintener has closed the issue without solving the problem.
I have trained, and pruned a model and saved the best model with a callback :

```
best_with_everything = ModelCheckpoint(logdir +'/' + \
                                    'best_with_everything.h5',
                                    monitor='val_loss', save_weights_only=False,
                                    save_best_only=True, period=1)
```

However, I can't load this model with this simple script:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras_YOLOv3.yolo3 import model

model = load_model("home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/tests_pruning_hugo/prune_tout/logs/best_with_everything.h5")
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    model = load_model("home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/tests_pruning_hugo/prune_tout/logs/best_with_everything.h5")
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1032, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 991, in process_node
    layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 687, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "/home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/yolo3/model.py", line 410, in yolo_loss
    mf = K.cast(m, K.dtype(yolo_outputs[0]))
NameError: name 'yolo_head' is not defined
```

I have model.py in keras_YOLOv3/yolo3 and the functions yolo_loss and yolo_head inside it.
yolo_loss:

```
def yolo_loss(args, anchors, num_classes, ignore_thresh=.5, print_loss=False):
    '''Return yolo_loss tensor

    Parameters
    ----------
    yolo_outputs: list of tensor, the output of yolo_body or tiny_yolo_body
    y_true: list of array, the output of preprocess_true_boxes
    anchors: array, shape=(N, 2), wh
    num_classes: integer
    ignore_thresh: float, the iou threshold whether to ignore object confidence loss

    Returns
    -------
    loss: tensor, shape=(1,)

    '''
    #from keras_YOLOv3.yolo3.model import yolo_head
    print("yolo_loss")
    
    num_layers = len(anchors)//3 # default setting
    print("num_layer", num_layers)
    yolo_outputs = args[:num_layers]
    y_true = args[num_layers:]
    print("y_true", y_true)
    anchor_mask = [[6,7,8], [3,4,5], [0,1,2]] if num_layers==3 else [[3,4,5], [1,2,3]]
    input_shape = K.cast(K.shape(yolo_outputs[0])[1:3] * 32, K.dtype(y_true[0]))
    grid_shapes = [K.cast(K.shape(yolo_outputs[l])[1:3], K.dtype(y_true[0])) for l in range(num_layers)]
    loss = 0
    m = K.shape(yolo_outputs[0])[0] # batch size, tensor
    mf = K.cast(m, K.dtype(yolo_outputs[0]))

    for l in range(num_layers):
        object_mask = y_true[l][..., 4:5]
        true_class_probs = y_true[l][..., 5:]

        grid, raw_pred, pred_xy, pred_wh = yolo_head(yolo_outputs[l],
             anchors[anchor_mask[l]], num_classes, input_shape, calc_loss=True)
        pred_box = K.concatenate([pred_xy, pred_wh])

        # Darknet raw box to calculate loss.
        raw_true_xy = y_true[l][..., :2]*grid_shapes[l][::-1] - grid
        raw_true_wh = K.log(y_true[l][..., 2:4] / anchors[anchor_mask[l]] * input_shape[::-1])
        raw_true_wh = K.switch(object_mask, raw_true_wh, K.zeros_like(raw_true_wh)) # avoid log(0)=-inf
        box_loss_scale = 2 - y_true[l][...,2:3]*y_true[l][...,3:4]

        # Find ignore mask, iterate over each of batch.
        ignore_mask = tf.TensorArray(K.dtype(y_true[0]), size=1, dynamic_size=True)
        object_mask_bool = K.cast(object_mask, 'bool')
        def loop_body(b, ignore_mask):
            true_box = tf.boolean_mask(y_true[l][b,...,0:4], object_mask_bool[b,...,0])
            iou = box_iou(pred_box[b], true_box)
            best_iou = K.max(iou, axis=-1)
            ignore_mask = ignore_mask.write(b, K.cast(best_iou<ignore_thresh, K.dtype(true_box)))
            return b+1, ignore_mask   
        if tf_version > parse_version('1.13.1'):
            # remove K.control_flow_ops and use one from tf (see import above)
            _, ignore_mask = control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda b,*args: b<m, loop_body, [0, ignore_mask])
        else:
            _, ignore_mask = K.control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda b,*args: b<m, loop_body, [0, ignore_mask])
        ignore_mask = ignore_mask.stack()
        ignore_mask = K.expand_dims(ignore_mask, -1)

        # K.binary_crossentropy is helpful to avoid exp overflow.
        xy_loss = object_mask * box_loss_scale * K.binary_crossentropy(raw_true_xy, raw_pred[...,0:2], from_logits=True)
        wh_loss = object_mask * box_loss_scale * 0.5 * K.square(raw_true_wh-raw_pred[...,2:4])
        confidence_loss = object_mask * K.binary_crossentropy(object_mask, raw_pred[...,4:5], from_logits=True)+ \
            (1-object_mask) * K.binary_crossentropy(object_mask, raw_pred[...,4:5], from_logits=True) * ignore_mask
        class_loss = object_mask * K.binary_crossentropy(true_class_probs, raw_pred[...,5:], from_logits=True)

        xy_loss = K.sum(xy_loss) / mf
        wh_loss = K.sum(wh_loss) / mf
        confidence_loss = K.sum(confidence_loss) / mf
        class_loss = K.sum(class_loss) / mf
        loss += xy_loss + wh_loss + confidence_loss + class_loss
        if print_loss:
            loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss, xy_loss, wh_loss, confidence_loss, class_loss, K.sum(ignore_mask)], message='loss: ')
    return loss
```

yolo_head:

```
def yolo_head(feats, anchors, num_classes, input_shape, calc_loss=False):
    """Convert final layer features to bounding box parameters."""
    num_anchors = len(anchors)
    # Reshape to batch, height, width, num_anchors, box_params.
    anchors_tensor = K.reshape(K.constant(anchors), [1, 1, 1, num_anchors, 2])

    grid_shape = K.shape(feats)[1:3] # height, width
    grid_y = K.tile(K.reshape(K.arange(0, stop=grid_shape[0]), [-1, 1, 1, 1]),
        [1, grid_shape[1], 1, 1])
    grid_x = K.tile(K.reshape(K.arange(0, stop=grid_shape[1]), [1, -1, 1, 1]),
        [grid_shape[0], 1, 1, 1])
    grid = K.concatenate([grid_x, grid_y])
    grid = K.cast(grid, K.dtype(feats))

    feats = K.reshape(
        feats, [-1, grid_shape[0], grid_shape[1], num_anchors, num_classes + 5])

    # Adjust preditions to each spatial grid point and anchor size.
    box_xy = (K.sigmoid(feats[..., :2]) + grid) / K.cast(grid_shape[...,::-1], K.dtype(feats))
    box_wh = K.exp(feats[..., 2:4]) * anchors_tensor / K.cast(input_shape[...,::-1], K.dtype(feats))
    box_confidence = K.sigmoid(feats[..., 4:5])
    box_class_probs = K.sigmoid(feats[..., 5:])

    if calc_loss == True:
        return grid, feats, box_xy, box_wh
    return box_xy, box_wh, box_confidence, box_class_probs
```

I tried to explicity import these two functions with `from keras_YOLOv3.yolo3.model import yolo_head, yolo_loss` and load the model with `model = load_model("home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/tests_pruning_hugo/prune_tout/logs/best_with_everything.h5", custom_objects={'yolo_loss': yolo_loss})` but still get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = load_model("/home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/tests_pruning_hugo/prune_tout/logs/best_with_everything.h5", custom_objects={'yolo_loss': model.yolo_loss})
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1032, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 991, in process_node
    layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hugo/.pyenv/versions/benchmark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 687, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "/home/hugo/Documents/011146_SMART-DATA/projet-ia/training-eval/keras_YOLOv3/yolo3/model.py", line 410, in yolo_loss
    mf = K.cast(m, K.dtype(yolo_outputs[0]))
NameError: name 'yolo_head' is not defined
```

Also, I'm working in a virtual environment with python 3.6.5.
Any advice on what I can do to get this working ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The error is inside model.py inside yolo_loss. Are you sure the yolo_head is defined directly at the global scope? (Not inside any weird ifs, not inside any weird classes... just `def yolo_head(...)` line starting without any spaces) If yes, make sure your files are saved and that you're running correct file. You can also try putting yolo_head definition above yolo_loss definition, but for functions it shouldn't matter...

Comment: No, to me there isn't something weird in yolo_head, and it's define before yolo_loss. That's why I'm really confused, and have no idea where the issue lies.